# Why this unpacking of arguments does not work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argument-unpacking

I get an error `type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple`.

I have this code:
`create_character = player.Create(**generate_player.generate())`

this is `player.py` module:

```
class Create(object):

    def __init__(self,name,age,gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
```

this is `generate_player.py` module:

```
import prompt

def generate():

    print "Name:"
    name = prompt.get_name()
    print "Age:"
    age = prompt.get_age()
    print "Gender M/F:"
    gender = prompt.get_gender()

    return name, age, gender
```

The `prompt` module is just bunch of `raw_input`s that return either string or integers (int for `age`).

Why is it returning tuples? When I run `print type` in `generate_player` module I get string, int, string for my arguments.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `**` syntax requires a **mapping** (such as a **dictionary**); each key-value pair in the mapping becomes a keyword argument.

Your `generate()` function, on the other hand, returns a tuple, not a dictionary. You can pass in a tuple as separate arguments with similar syntax, using just **one** asterisk:

```
create_character = player.Create(*generate_player.generate())
```

Alternatively, fix your `generate()` function to return a dictionary:

```
def generate():
    print "Name:"
    name = prompt.get_name()
    print "Age:"
    age = prompt.get_age()
    print "Gender M/F:"
    gender = prompt.get_gender()

    return {'name': name, 'age': age, 'gender': gender}
```

Comment: I just found out using `create_character = player.Create(*generate_player.generate())` is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: How is mapping defined here? In other words, can I make any class **-unpackable? Same question for *-unpackables

Comment: @Bananach: See [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping), so anything that has the [`collections.abc.Mappings` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes). `*` requires an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Answer (score 11):

You just want a single asterisk:

```
create_character = player.Create(*generate_player.generate())
```

You're passing a sequence of arguments, for which you use one asterisk.  The double-asterisk syntax is for passing a mapping, for instance to do something like this:

```
player.Create(**{'name': 'Richie', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'male'})
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in my case I left a comma `,` at the end of the definition of the dictionary, e.g.,

```
params = {...}, 

f(**params)
```

and `params` is a 1-tuple now with the dictionary being its element, hence the error... Removing the comma resolves it.